# Computer wakes from sleep instantly. No lastwake information

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power

My parents' computer wakes instantly when put to sleep. It spins down and then starts a second later.

There are no devices set to wake, lastwake gives no information, eventvwr is empty, and the power profile does not allows scheduled tasks to wake it from sleep.

See below.

```
C:\Users\User>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed


C:\Users\User>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
```

**This seems to have started after a recent thunderstorm.** It apparently fried the NIC which was not working. I disabled it in the BIOS and added a USB WIFI adapter. Is it possible that physical damage is signalling the computer to wake? Would this be fixable? The computer is old but more than adequate for their needs.

Comment: Did you ever find any resolution to this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: @miR no and unfortunately I'm now in another city so can't continue looking. For now I'm assuming this is due to hardware damage as suggested but everything else is working fine.

Comment: Some suggestions 1) disable any wakeup features in BIOS (including keyboard) and 2) replace the BIOS battery

Comment: @GeekyDaddy thanks for the reply but I 'fixed' it by replacing the motherboard so it may have been a battery issue but probably hardware. Since then they got hit by lightning a 2nd time, frying the onboard NIC. They had a surge protector but it went through the phone line, modem, and ethernet cable, burning out the ports on both ends. I guess some people have all the luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem was probably caused by damaged hardware that has been replaced (so not reproducible).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem was probably caused by damaged hardware that has been replaced (so not reproducible).